# Issue when installing blitzjs and ionic togther, related to es6-module

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, es6-modules, blitz.js

When I try to install blitzjs and ionic together, it fails. It is quite easy to reproduce the issue.

```sh
npm install -g blitz
blitz new blitz-ionic

✔ Pick a new project's language · JavaScript
✔ Pick your new app template · full
✔ Install dependencies? · npm
✔ Pick a form library (you can switch to something else later if you want) · React Final Form


cd blitz-ionic/
npm install --save @ionic/react @ionic/react-router history react-router-dom
```

Then add this line to the file `app/pages/_app.tsx`

```js
import { IonReactRouter } from "@ionic/react-router"
```

Now, when I run

```
blitz build
```

I obtain the following error:

```
> Build error occurred
/home/XXXXX/test/blitz-ionic/node_modules/@ionic/core/components/index.js:4
export { setAssetPath, setPlatformOptions } from '@stencil/core/internal/client';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
```

I have tried a lot but I have no idea what is going on and how to solve it...

I got the issue whether I choose typescript or javascript during blitzjs install.

If I comment the line that I just added, it works fine.

If I install just blitzjs, or just ionic, it works perfectly.

Comment: which version of node are you using? i followed your instructions using node v16.13.0 and it built with no issue.

Comment: Actually never mind, I tried again following the same inputs as above (javascript, full template), and now I'm seeing the same error